# Auto fill a form from a different website

Tags: javascript, php, forms, autofill

We have a webshop and using the shop's API we're able to fetch orders. On the other hand we have our wholesaler but they don't have an API, so we can't post orders to their system. They do have an online ordering form. Is there any way to auto fill this form from our script on our server to their script on their server?

I was googling the topic but I came across scripts that fill forms from the same page, not a different page on a different server.

p.s. this question is not intended to create spamming bots ;)

Comment: If they allow it, you should be able to POST to it using cURL.

Comment: I'm afraid that won't work, because the ordering form is behind a loginpage. I can't bypass that by using cURL I believe.

Answer (score 0):

if i really understand that what u asked i think u must should use Selenium Web Driver that u can get information from a link and use them to auto fill the desired form , Selenium available on Java, Python , Ruby and ...